# ASP.NET DataSet from Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, oracle, dataset

I have read so many questions and articles from this web site.
However I am getting tired of looking for something I want to manipulate.
In SQL Server, I used to call procedures like "EXEC Some_Procedure_name arg1, 'arg2', arg3, 'arg4'".
When input parameters are in numeric, I woudn't use sing quotation.
But in oracle, do I really need to write something like using Input and Output parameters?
Let's say that the procedure is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_JOB
(
    p_JOB_ID IN varchar2,
    outCursor OUT MYGEN.sqlcur
)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN outCursor FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM JOB
    WHERE JOB_ID = p_JOB_ID;
END GET_JOB;
/
```

Then I must specify the name of input parameter's name in my c# code like below:

```
var userNameParameter = command.Parameters.Add("p_JOB_ID", Job_ID); 
returnValueParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.In;
```

Can't I just call it like "Execute GET_JOB 'j208';"?

Answer (score 0):

To return datasets from a stored procedure in Oracle, you need to use a "REF CURSOR".

This is explained in detail, with code examples for .NET, here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/williams-refcursors-092375.html

Comment: thanks. I have read that article. By the way, maybe u have not read my question very carefully. I am not asking how to use output ref cursor. I already know how to use that. But I am asking how to use syntax like "Execute GET_JOB 'j208';" in oracle. Do u have any more suggestion?